# Algorithm for optimal expected amount in a profit/loss game

Tags: algorithm, probability

I came upon the following question recently,

"You have a box which has G green and B blue coins. Pick a random coin, G gives a profit of +1 and blue a loss of -1. If you play optimally what is the expected profit."

I was thinking of using a brute force algorithm where I consider all possibilities of combinations of green and blue coins but I'm sure there must be a better solution for this (range of B and G was from 0 to 5000). Also what does playing optimally mean? Does it mean that if i pick all blue coins then I would continue playing till all green coins are also picked? If so then this means I shouldn't consider all possibilities of green and blue coins?

Comment: I think play optimally means you choose when to stop picking coins.

Comment: The given instructions simply say to pick a random coin (singular).  The player has no choice here, thus there is no strategy.  You pick a coin, and your expected result is (G-B) / (G+B).  Obviously, this is not what you intended, so please elaborate.

Comment: The question asks to find the expectation of profit from such a game, ans hence we have to not only consider picking a singular coin but all possibilities, since the player can make multiple picks and stop when he desires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "obvious" answer is to play whenever there's more green coins than blue coins. In fact, this is wrong. For example, if there's 999 green coins and 1000 blue coins, here's a strategy that takes an expected profit:

```
Take 2 coins
If GG -- stop with a profit of 2
if BG or GB -- stop with a profit of 0
if BB -- take all the remaining coins for a profit of -1
```

Since the first and last possibilities both occur with near 25% probability, your overall expectation is approximately 0.25*2 - 0.25*1 = 0.25

This is just a simple strategy in one extreme example that shows that the problem is not as simple as it first seems.

In general, the expectations with `g` green coins and `b` blue coins is given by a recurrence relation:

```
E(g, 0) = g
E(0, b) = 0
E(g, b) = max(0, g(E(g-1, b) + 1)/(b+g) + b(E(g, b-1) - 1)/(b+g))
```

The max in the final row occurs because if it's -EV to play, then you're better stopping.

These recurrence relations can be solved using dynamic programming in O(gb) time.

```
from fractions import Fraction as F

def gb(G, B):
    E = [[F(0, 1)] * (B+1) for _ in xrange(G+1)]
    for g in xrange(G+1):
        E[g][0] = F(g, 1)
    for b in xrange(1, B+1):
        for g in xrange(1, G+1):
            E[g][b] = max(0, (g * (E[g-1][b]+1) + b * (E[g][b-1]-1)) * F(1, (b+g)))
    for row in E:
        for v in row:
            print '%5.2f' % v,
        print
    print
    return E[G][B]

print gb(8, 10)
```

Output:

```
 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 1.00  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 2.00  1.33  0.67  0.20  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 3.00  2.25  1.50  0.85  0.34  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 4.00  3.20  2.40  1.66  1.00  0.44  0.07  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 5.00  4.17  3.33  2.54  1.79  1.12  0.55  0.15  0.00  0.00  0.00
 6.00  5.14  4.29  3.45  2.66  1.91  1.23  0.66  0.23  0.00  0.00
 7.00  6.12  5.25  4.39  3.56  2.76  2.01  1.34  0.75  0.30  0.00
 8.00  7.11  6.22  5.35  4.49  3.66  2.86  2.11  1.43  0.84  0.36

7793/21879
```

From this you can see that the expectation is positive to play with 8 green and 10 blue coins (EV=7793/21879 ~= 0.36), and you even have positive expectation with 2 green and 3 blue coins (EV=0.2)

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is wrong; see Paul Hankin's answer for counterexamples and a proper analysis.**  I leave this answer here as a learning example for all of us.

---

Assuming that your choice is only when to stop picking coins, you continue as long as G > B.  That part is simple.  If you start with G < B, then you never start drawing, and your gain is 0.  For G = B, no strategy will get you a mathematical advantage; the gain there is also 0.

For the expected reward, take this in two steps:

(1) Expected value on any draw sequence.  Do this recursively, figuring the chance of getting green or blue on the first draw, and then the expected values for the new state (G-1, B) or (G, B-1).  You will quickly see that the expected value of any given draw *number* (such as all possibilities for the 3rd draw) is the same as the original.

Therefore, your expected value on *any* draw is **e = (G-B) / (G+B)**.  Your overall expected value is **e * d**, where d is the number of draws you choose.

(2) What is the expected number of draws?  How many times do you expect to draw before G = B?  I'll leave this as an exercise for the student, but note the previous idea of doing this recursively.  You might find it easier to describe the state of the game as (extra, total), where **extra = G-B** and **total = G+B**.

Illustrative exercise: given G=4, B=2, what is the chance that you'll draw GG on the first two draws (and then stop the game)?  What is the gain from that?  How does that compare with the (4-2)/(4+2) advantage on each draw?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please elaborate a bit on how the xpected value is same for any given draw number. For instance in the example G=4 and B=2, chance of drawing GG is 4/6 x 3/5 which is not the same as (4-2/4+2). I think I''m misunderstanding something here..

Comment: I think you made a sign error (or I don't understand your comment about the ev of any draw is (G-B)/(G+B). Because (G-1-B)/(G+B-1) != (G-(B-1))/(G+B-1)

Comment: Also, this answer is wrong -- it can be correct to play when G<B. See my answer for a counterexample (G=3, B=4) and a simple strategy that demonstrates a positive EV when G=999, B=1000.

Comment: @PaulHankin: thanks.  I tried to follow that logic path and blew it.  For now, I'll leave my answer here as an example of logic *not* to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and intuitive answer:

you should start off with an estimate for the total number of blue and green coins. After each pick you will update this estimate. If you estimate there are more blue coins than green coins at any point you should stop.

Example:

you start and you pick a coin. Its green so you estimate 100% of the coins are green. You pick a blue so you estimate 50% of coins are green. You pick another blue coin so you estimate 33% of the coins are green. At this point is isn't worth playing anymore, according to your estimate, so you stop.

Comment: This is wrong -- it can be correct to play when G<B.